# creating python plot with different color lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I'm trying to produce a simple plot which reads x,y values stored in files and plots them using a different color for each line. Below is my attempt.

```
## to run ctrl+shift+b

#print("hello world")

import csv
import itertools
import pylab
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


f =  open('2016-09-09-22_25_A_initial-Hysteresis.txt', 'r')
f2 =  open('2016-09-09-22_25_F_initial-Hysteresis.txt', 'r')
f3 =  open('2016-09-09-22_25_K_initial-Hysteresis.txt', 'r')
f4 =  open('2016-09-09-22_25_P_initial-Hysteresis.txt', 'r')
f5 =  open('2016-09-09-22_25_U_initial-Hysteresis.txt', 'r')
f6 =  open('2016-09-09-22_26_A_initial-Hysteresis.txt', 'r')
f7 =  open('2016-09-09-22_26_F_initial-Hysteresis.txt', 'r')
f8 =  open('2016-09-09-22_26_K_initial-Hysteresis.txt', 'r')
f9 =  open('2016-09-09-22_26_P_initial-Hysteresis.txt', 'r')
f10 =  open('2016-09-09-22_26_U_initial-Hysteresis.txt', 'r')

x = f.readlines()
x2 = f2.readlines()
x3 = f3.readlines()
x4 = f4.readlines()
x5 = f5.readlines()
x6 = f6.readlines()
x7 = f7.readlines()
x8 = f8.readlines()
x9 = f9.readlines()
x10 = f10.readlines()

vars = [x, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10]
colors = ['b', 'r', 'g', 'c']
cc = itertools.cycle(colors)


datatable = []
i = 0
for content in vars:


    for line_num, line_content in enumerate(content):
        data = line_content.split()
        row = [[], [], [], []]


        for index, num in enumerate(data, start = 0):

            isappendable = False


            try:
                data_attempt = float(num)
                index = int(index)
                row[index] = data_attempt
                if(line_num > 15):
                    isappendable = True

            except ValueError:
                data_attempt = 0

        if(isappendable):
            datatable.append(row)

    i = i + 1

    c = next(cc)
    index = []
    input = []
    output = []
    for n,x in enumerate(datatable):

        input.append(x[0])
        output.append(x[1])

    num_str = str(i)
    name = "DUT" + num_str
    plt.plot(input, output,  label = name)

plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

When I execute the code I get the following image.[image]

This looks pretty close to what I want (there are 10 lines which significantly overlap with each other) but the problem I have is that the colors in the legend do not seem to match the colors in the plot. The legend shows the colors that I would like the plots to be but the lines are all the same (even when I zoom in on them). How would I fix this? Thank you

Comment: It looks like you are plotting the same data 10 times and hence what you see is just the last data in greenish color. Re-check your code or your data. Try plotting only upto DUT9 and see if you only get the color corresponding to DUT9.

Comment: plt.plot(input, output,  label = name, color=colors[line_num])

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code to try and find what is wrong and identified a few things that you should change.

1. You can use a for loop instead of manually creating a variable for each file.
2. Using the `with` context manager will take care of cleanup after you are done with the file.
3. `vars` and `input` are reserved keywords in Python, so while you *can* use them (and it will probably work), it's probably better to use something else.
4. You can use `enumerate`, like you've done for the other for loops, instead of using `i`.
5. You don't need to specify `start = 0` because that is the default value anyway.
6. You do not need to do `int(index)` because index is already an `int`.
7. Don't mix up and repeat variable names like you've done with `x` and `index`, it makes them harder to keep track of.
8. **I think your main issue is your `datatable`, which should be initialised in the loop.** Otherwise, you are plotting the same thing over again as @Bazingaa says.
9. You've used enumerate to declare `n` but you never use it.
10. You declare an `index` array but never use it.
11. The `num_str` variable does not serve a purpose.

I addressed some of these things below:

```
import csv
import itertools
import pylab
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors = ['b', 'r', 'g', 'c']
cc = itertools.cycle(colors)


# List of filenames to read
filenames = ["2016-09-09-22_25_A_initial-Hysteresis.txt", "2016-09-09-22_25_F_initial-Hysteresis.txt", ...]

for i, filename in enumerate(filenames):
    with open ("/path/to/filename/"+filename) as f:
        content = f.readlines()

        datatable = []

        for line_num, line_content in enumerate(content):
            data = line_content.split()
            row = [[], [], [], []]


            for index, num in enumerate(data):

                isappendable = False

                try:
                    data_attempt = float(num)
                    row[index] = data_attempt
                    if line_num > 15:
                        isappendable = True

                except ValueError:
                    data_attempt = 0

            if(isappendable):
                datatable.append(row)

        c = next(cc)

        input = []
        output = []

        for x in datatable:
            input.append(x[0])
            output.append(x[1])

        name = "DUT" + i
        plt.plot(input, output,  label = name)

plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the complete code can be simplified to a couple of lines.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# List of filenames to read
filenames = ["2016-09-09-22_25_A_initial-Hysteresis.txt", 
             "2016-09-09-22_25_F_initial-Hysteresis.txt",
             # ...
             "2016-09-09-22_26_U_initial-Hysteresis.txt"]

for i, filename in enumerate(filenames):
    inp, outp = np.loadtxt(filename, usecols=(0,1), unpack=True)
    if len(inp) < 15:
        continue
    plt.plot(inp, outp,  label = "DUT" + i)

plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```